# object has no _state

Tags: python, django, django-models

In my Django app I have model:

```
class Voivodeship(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=20, primary_key=True)
```

I also have script to build my database from raw data:

```
import app.models as models
...
voivodeships[name] = models.Voivodeship(name=name)
voivodeships[name].save()
```

But when I try to interpret it in `python manage.py shell` using exec (`exec(open('filler.py').read())`) it returns error:

```
'Voivodeship' object has no attribute '_state'
```

And I don't know what's going on. Can you suggest me any solution?

Comment: Why even bother adding that `__init__` which will just shadow the field? Your script could just be changed to say `voiv[name] = models.Voiv(name=name)` and work just fine

Comment: I've changed it to `models.Voivodeship(name=name)` and removed '__init__`, but it didn't helped

Comment: What does "interpret it in manage.py (using exec)" mean?

Comment: Ok, I've added explanation